# Variable increments not working in for loop

Tags: java

I have this code below:

```
int males = 100;
    for (int i=0;i>100;i+=1){
        males+=1000;
    }
    System.out.println(males);
```

The result is just 100. Shouldn't the outcome be a really large number?

Comment: I'll give you a hint. try to figure out how many times the loop runs, and why

Comment: No.  This code is correctly producing 100.  Voting to close as off-topic as your issue is down to a typo and thus unlikely to be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes it helps to have a second set of eyes.
your code will continue to execute when `i>100;`. Flip that > into a < and you're good to go

Comment: In order to encourage a high quality of questions, please try to avoid answering questions that do not fit the guidelines outlined in the [help].

Comment: @JoeC I believe this only applies when we know that the OP has the correct fundamental understanding of how a for-loop works. Have you considered that maybe OP thought that his comparison operator was correct? It's difficult to identify a 1-character typo when 1) you are a beginner, and 2) neither the IDE nor the compiler point them out, because the code is syntactically correct. You can suggest he read more docs, but at what level of complexity do we draw the "this question doesn't merit an answer" line? Food for thought on every single comment downvoted here.

Comment: All of the answers to the questions you've raised can be found in the [help] and on [meta].

Comment: Heres from the help center: questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior ("Shouldn't the outcome be a really large number?"), a specific problem or error ("The result is just 100") and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself (code is provided). According to the help center, this question is valid.

Comment: Also from the [help]: "Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error [are off-topic]. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."

Comment: And that is the exact point that I am challenging. *If* the OP does not know how a for-loop works fundamentally, it is not a typographical error, it is a logical error, which may absolutely be answered in a fashion which can be helpful to future readers (like explaining what the arguments of the for-loop do). By down-voting without considering this, you may be preventing another possible learning platform that these question/answer's create.

Comment: If the OP asked specifically about that point, then I would agree with you.

Comment: There's no way to say one way or the other. Why not give the benefit of the doubt?

Answer (score -2):

You have the comparison wrong way, it never steps into for loop.
Do it like this "for (int i=0;i<100;i+=1)"

Comment: In order to encourage a high quality of questions, please try to avoid answering questions that do not fit the guidelines outlined in the [help].